# Out of Stack Space - Replacing Text in a Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to search within formulae for a specific piece of a formula and then replace it with a new piece. To achieve this, I have used the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Range("B1").Value = "National" Then
        For i = 1 To 135
            Range("C" & i).Formula = Replace(Range("C" & i).Formula, "SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR,$B$1,", "SUM(")
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

When I change the value in cell B1 to *National*, the code runs and then completes with Error 28 - Out of Stack Space. I click OK, Excel crashes and restarts. In the recovered file, all of the instances of the text have been replaced as desired.

So technically the code works, I just need to not have Excel crash every time it runs. Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Comment: Turn calculation and event handling off. You are running on top of yourself by changing the formula(s) in the cell(s).

Comment: Surely you do not want to run/rerun this whenever anything in the entire worksheet changes. What condition should this be triggered on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running recursively, triggering an event cascade. That is: every time your code accesses the worksheet it fires itself off again. Avoid it by setting the `.EnableEvents` Application property to `False` or `True` as needed

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264523(v=vs.60).aspx

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("B1").Value = "National" Then
        For i = 1 To 135
            Range("C" & i).Formula = Replace(Range("C" & i).Formula, "SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR,$B$1,", "SUM(")
        Next i
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to just disable the code all together. I need the code to run any time B1 changes and stop running after it reaches C135.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention and didn't realize my macros were disabled. I'll report back once I test the code out with them enabled.     Edit: It worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Suspend various environment settings during execution.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Dim i As Long
        If Range("B1").Value = "National" Then
            For i = 1 To 135
                Range("C" & i).Formula = Replace(Range("C" & i).Formula, "SUMIF('Site Data '!$CR:$CR,$B$1,", "SUM(")
            Next i
        End If
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

You are retriggering the event macro by writing new formulas so temporarily suspend event handling. Similarly, there is no need to recalculate within your loop; only after all formulas have been changed.

Comment: Ooopps! Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Change event which will be called for every value/formula change, I would recommend using non-volatile Excel formula instead if possible:

```
= If( $B$1 = "National", SUMIF_formula, SUM_formula )
```

In addition to making the sheet slower and less responsive than needed, relying on the Change event without understanding it can lead to some other unexpected issues. For example: macros blocked by the Trust Center or by the user, changes to ranges or sheet name, saving the workbook in a format that doesn't allow VBA such as .xlsx, etc.